# Цикл на Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, arm

Не могу понять, что выполняет данная программа, точнее, как именно организован цикл здесь.(Для `ARM`)  Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
ADDS R5, #1
MOVS R4, #0xE
CMP R5, R4
BNE skip
MOVS R5, 0
Skip
LDR R4, 0x30
ADDS R4, R5
STR R4, [R0, #UA_THR]
```

Comment: тут нет цикла. тут есть только переход на метку Skip (обход инструкции movs R5, 0) в случае если R5 не равен R4. т.е. в начале буквально сказано, `r5=1; r4=0x0e; if(r4==r5) r5=0; ...`

Comment: после этого (если я правильно понял) мы грузим в R4 адрес из ячейки памяти по смещению 0x30 прибавляем его к R4 с обновлением флагов, после чего сограняем его в ячейку памяти по адресу R0+#UA_THR

Comment: Понял ,спасибо. Просто считал adds r5, #1 как r5=r5+1 и сразу подумал про цикл

Comment: Ой, не досмотрел, да там сложение конечно, как вы и говорите. но дальше я все верно написал (вроде :) )

Comment: Когда будет цикл, переход будет скорее всего куда нибудь назад, т.е. на предшествующие инструкции